# MVC 4 Href or onclick without Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, postback

I have a Question related to MVC postbacks
the problem/issue is

i have an anchor with the following code

```
<a style="text-align:left;" data-role="button" onclick="window.location='@Url.Action("Taken_Detail", new { TaakID = tk.ID }) + " data-ajax="true" data-icon="alert"><span class="AgenItems"></span>
```

if i click on it it would redirect me to the current page Taken_Detail with the ID 
thats nice but it would happend with an postback / Page flicker how to avoid that ?
if i use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Toezicht", "Toezicht", "Toezicht", new { data_transition = "none" })
```

than my page won't have a white page flickering ?

Comment: So what is your question? You seem to already have a solution to the "flicker" issue

Comment: no because its inside an anchor that i render with an StringBuilder

Comment: musefan indeed can use actionlink

Comment: @Ajax.ActionLink http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx